# Installing Android using only fastboot on HTC Vision

Tags: rom-flashing, htc-desire-z, fastboot, bootloader, unbricking

I lost my system somehow. My phone turned off and reboots during starting up.

I'm only able to go to hboot (fastboot/recovery etc.) on my phone, and I'm unable to run Android system.

I have tried many possible solutions with help of #g2root on freenode:

1. First I downloaded the stock ROM and saved it to SD card (PC10IMG.zip).

   - It begins to load, and I see [1]-[12] positions.
   - When I agree to install, there's "- Updating" text near to "[1] Bootloader". Nothing else happens for more than 30 minutes.
2. Then we tried to get rom.zip from official HTC Unlocker for Desire Z, saving it to the SD card.

   - This time the only list item there was "[1] Bootloader" and also "Updating" text and nothing happens.
3. The last thing I tried was to run EXE file from HTC that is supposed to update my HBOOT.

   - It also doesn't work.

Here are my HBOOT params:

> VISION PVT SHIP S-ON
>   ?HBOOT-0.85.0013
>   MICROP-0425
>   RADIO-26.10.04.03_M
>   eMMC-boot
>   Apr 11 2011,23:36:27

Is there anything else I can try to recover my phone?

Comment: Have you tried running `fastboot flash zip rom.zip` from a connected pc?

Comment: Yes, and it also hangs.